# Getting extent of layer in QGIS

Tags: qgis, layers, vector, extents

Is there a way to get the extent (bbox) of a vector layer in QGIS?

I see that I can update the extent, but I am looking for the actual coordinates of the extent.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The layer extents are available in the Layer Properties | Metadata section | [Extent](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/vector_properties.html#metadata-properties).

[image]

Answer (score 13):

To get a bounding box in QGIS as a new vector layer use the ["Extract layer extent"](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/layertools.html?highlight=research%20tools#extract-layer-extent):
`Vector -> Research Tools -> Extract layer extent`

[image]

Comment: I don't really want to create a new file. I am only interested in the four coordinates.

Comment: You could just use extract the nodes of the newly created polgygon and use the Export/Add geometry columns tool to get the corner coordinates. Put everything into a Processing model and it runs in no time...?

Comment: Note: This works for raster layers too

Answer (score 2):

PostGIS has the [`ST_Extent()`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Extent.html) function which generates a bounding box for you. So my approach would be to export the layer to a database. if you want id, name, geom, bounding box just do

```sql
select id, name, geom, ST_Extent(geom)
from your_table group by id
```

Answer (score 2):

From the (right-click) context menu of the desired layer, choose Export => Save Feature As...

[image: Layer Context Menu: Export -> Save Feature As...]

In the dialog that appears, you can ignore all inputs and just scroll down to the Extent section and enable the checkbox.

[image: Save Feature As Dialog: Extent Section]

So for a standard bbox array of [minx,miny,maxx,maxy] your values would be [west,south,east,north].

Answer (score 2):

There are several possibilities by means of the PyQGIS

1. Using the [`.boundingBoxOfSelected()`](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.0/core/Vector/QgsVectorLayer.html#qgis.core.QgsVectorLayer.boundingBoxOfSelected) method

```py
layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('test')[0]
layer.selectAll()
extent = layer.boundingBoxOfSelected()
print(extent)
layer.removeSelection()
```

2. Using the [`.extent()`](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.0/core/Vector/QgsVectorLayer.html#qgis.core.QgsVectorLayer.extent) method

```py
layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('test')[0]
extent = layer.extent()
print(extent)
```

In both cases, the result will end up in a form of:

```
<QgsRectangle: 435177.19075885589700192 5645765.28368342109024525, 435464.76195503829512745 5645985.34679672587662935>
```

To get a more visually pleasing result, please extend the code with an approach mentioned in [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/245817/99589)

```py
xmin = extent.xMinimum()
xmax = extent.xMaximum()
ymin = extent.yMinimum()
ymax = extent.yMaximum()

print('XMin:{0}, XMax:{1}, YMin:{2}, YMax:{3}'.format(xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax))
```

this will lead in

```
XMin:435177.1907588559, XMax:435464.7619550383, YMin:5645765.283683421, YMax:5645985.346796726
```

Answer (score 2):

It is also possible to get the extent within the Field Calculator by means of the [`layer_property()`](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/functions_list.html#layer-property) function and its `extent` parameter, and a bunch of: [`x_min`](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/functions_list.html#x-max), [`x_max`](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/functions_list.html#x-max), [`y_min`](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/functions_list.html#y-min), and [`y_max`](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/functions_list.html#y-max).

```
x_min(layer_property('test', 'extent')) || ' ' || x_max(layer_property('test', 'extent')) || ' ' || y_min(layer_property('test', 'extent')) || ' ' || y_max(layer_property('test', 'extent'))
```

This expression will lead to this result:

```
435177.1907588559 435464.7619550383 5645765.283683421 5645985.346796726
```

Answer (score 0):

Also similar to [@underdark's answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/85202/99589), you may see under the Information | [Information from provider](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/vector_properties.html#information-properties)

[image: extent]

The extent is provided in the following order: `xmin,ymin : xmax,ymax`