# V.transform in Qgis script

Tags: pyqgis

I'm trying to create my first script with qgis.
I began with graphical modeler but some bugs block me to do calculation on variables.
So I decide to write it myself.

I wrote that for the moment :

```
##Zonage_alamano=name
##point=vector
##sortie=output vector
##angle=number
##longueur=number
##largeur=number


demilargeur = (largeur)/2

angleinverse = -(angle)


reproj_1 = processing.runalg('qgis:reprojectlayer', point, 'EPSG:2154', None, progress=None)

enveloppe = processing.runalg('qgis:concavehull', reproj_1['OUTPUT'], 0.1, False, False, None, progress=None)

rotate1 = processing.runalg('grass7:v.transform', enveloppe['OUTPUT'],0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,1.0,1.0, angle, None,-1.0,0.0001,0,None, progress=None)

buffer = processing.runalg('qgis:fixeddistancebuffer', rotate1['OUTPUT'], demilargeur, 12, False, sortie)
```

But I have this message :

> 2017-09-05T16:42:11    1   Erreur : valeur du paramètre faux : None
>
> 2017-09-05T16:42:11    2   Uncaught error while executing algorithm
>
> Traceback (most recent call last): File "/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/plugins/processing/core/GeoAlgorithm.py", line 203, in execute
>                   self.processAlgorithm(progress)
>
> File "/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/plugins/processing/script/ScriptAlgorithm.py", line 378, in processAlgorithm
>                   exec((script), ns)
>
> File "", line 21, in 
>               TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '**getitem**'

I think issue come from v.transform treatment, because I made a test without it and it run well. I searched for information about writting v.transform in qgis script but I didn't find nothing...

Somebody have an idea to help me ?

Comment: Probably due to the `extent` parameter for *v.transform* which requires you to set an extent instead of leaving it as `None`. Check this post to see how to define the extent and try include this into the parameter: [Getting layer extent in PyQGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/245811/getting-layer-extent-in-pyqgis)

Comment: I tried to put 2 lines to have extent but it returns me iface is not defined...

Comment: You will need to use `from qgis.utils import iface` :)

Comment: Ok, but I've a new error :D `'NoneType' object has no attribut 'extent'`. I put the 2 lines for extent between concave hull and v.transform treatment.

Comment: I found something who works : `layer = processing.getObject(enveloppe['OUTPUT'])
ext = "%f,%f,%f,%f" %(layer.extent().xMinimum(), layer.extent().xMaximum(), layer.extent().yMinimum(), layer.extent().yMaximum())`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found solution with **Joseph** help.
`v.transform` need an extent as parameter just after angle.
So to have extent, just 2 lines :

```
layer = processing.getObject(your_vector_layer) #for me enveloppe['OUTPUT']
ext = "%f,%f,%f,%f" %(layer.extent().xMinimum(), layer.extent().xMaximum(), layer.extent().yMinimum(), layer.extent().yMaximum())
```

Put `ext` instead of extent parameter.
It works with others treatment like `vector grid` or any treatment who need an extent.