# Exporting layer extent information for 400 layers in QGIS?

Tags: qgis

I have over 400 layers, and I need to extract the extent information into a list.

Is there any way I can extract the extent for all 400 layers into a single file?

Copy and pasting one by one isn't practical.

Comment: To do an automation task this I think you should use PyQGIS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick google on GIS Stack Exchange has the following resources:

- [Loop through all layers](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/297424/61743)
- [Get the extent of current layer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/245817/61743)
- [Getting layer name](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/118865/61743)

Put those together with a simple csv write command using pyQGIS suggests the following as a first attempt:

```
with open ("outputfile.csv","w") as off:
    off.write("LAYERNAME,MINX,MAXX,MINY,MAXY")
    #get all map layers:
    layers = QgsProject.instance().mapLayers().values()
    #loop through layers 
    for layer in layers:
        #get extent of current layer
        ext = layer.extent()
        xmin = ext.xMinimum()
        xmax = ext.xMaximum()
        ymin = ext.yMinimum()
        ymax = ext.yMaximum()
        #write to csv file
        off.write("\n"+layer.name()+","+str(xmin)+","+str(xmax)+","+str(ymin)+","+str(ymax))
```

*Disclaimer*: put together from code snippets and not tested.  However this does give a quick idea of an initial method for further development.